# Show that $E=C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ is not a hilbert space ...

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Show that the prehilbertian space $E=C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ provided with the scalar product
$$ (x|y)=\int_0^1x(t)\bar y(t)dt$$is not a hilbert space!

I know that we have to show that $E$ is not complete but I cannot find any cauchy sequence which does not converge in $E$. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Find a sequence of continuous functions that converges to a step function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Verify that $f_n(x)=1$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac 1  2 $ $-\frac 1 n$, $n(\frac 1  2 -x)$ for  $\frac  1 2 -\frac 1  n \leq x \leq \frac  1 2$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $x >\frac  1 2$ defines a Cauchy sequence which does not converge to any element of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.